# Почему не работает replaceFirst?

Tags: java, char, replace

Не могу понять, почему не работает данный код:

```
char q ='.';
char AcharAt = message.charAt(0);
if (AcharAt==q){
    message.replaceFirst(".","");
}
```

Comment: Дайте угадаю - он меняет все символы на пустышки?

Comment: Нет, он просто не убирает точку

Comment: Если интересно могу скинуть больше кода

Comment: Он все убирает, но вы ведь не присваиваете результат этого действия никакой переменной. Наверное, забыли, что `String` - immutable...

Answer (score 4):

Вся ошибка состоит в том, что в Java нельзя менять строки или их изменять непосредственно. Для этого следует либо создавать новую переменную, либо перезаписывать в старую.

```
char q ='.';
String ans; 
char AcharAt = message.charAt(0);
if (AcharAt==q){
    ans = message.replaceFirst(".","");
}
```

Теперь переменная ans хранит результат функции.